# Subtract area from plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

The color of the 2 areas are added. Instead, I would like each new area to cover the previous ones with the color defined in the description.

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0.001:160, samples=100]
\begin{axis}[
    legend style={draw=none, legend columns=2, at={(.9,.9)}}]
    \addplot [fill=blue, opacity=.3, draw=none, forget plot] {.508-1.52398*exp(-(13702.2/x)^0.13266)} \closedcycle;
    \addplot [fill=violet, opacity=.3, draw=none, forget plot] {.445-0.34900*exp(-(30.0706/x)^0.23650)} \closedcycle;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. If you want the second area to cover the first one without transparency you can delete the option `opacity=0.3` or set it to 1 (`opacity=1`).

Comment: I mean that violet area is not violet, but violet+blue. I would like that each area color doesn't depend on the previous area. I can't delete `opacity` because I have to plot something else on these areas.

Comment: Whatever is plotted last goes on top (with opacity=1).  You may need to use \pgfplotsextra for tikz commands.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do that (if I understand correctly your question) is to use the `stack plots` option. First you plot the violet area and then the blue one using the difference of the two functions where it is positive. To avoid repeating the functions the option `declare function` can be employed.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0.001:160, samples=100]
\begin{axis}[
  legend style={draw=none, legend columns=2, at={(.9,.9)}},
  declare function={
    f1(\x) = .508-1.52398*exp(-(13702.2/\x)^0.13266);
    f2(\x) = .445-0.34900*exp(-(30.0706/\x)^0.23650);
    pos(\x) = ifthenelse(\x>0,\x,0);
  },
  stack plots=y,
  ]
  \addplot [fill=violet, opacity=.3, draw=none, forget plot] {f2(x)} \closedcycle;
  \addplot [fill=blue, opacity=.3, draw=none, forget plot] {pos(f1(x)-f2(x))} \closedcycle;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The resulting plot:

[image]

Comment: I have this error `! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `f2' (in 'f2(x)').`

Comment: @Stefano I don't know what to say. The code I posted works for me; which version of pgf and pgfplots are you using?